# characteristic functions and symmetry

Tags: mathematical-statistics, characteristic-function

If the characteristic function of a random variable is a real-valued function, does this imply that the random variable must be symmetric about zero?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  When the characteristic function $\phi_X$ of a random variable $X$ is real-valued, that means

$$\overline{\phi_X}(t) = \phi_X(t)$$

for all $t$.  But for *any* characteristic function

$$\phi_{-X}(t) = \phi_X(-t) = \overline{\phi_X}(t),$$

showing that $X$ and $-X$ have identical distributions (since the cf determines the distribution), implying [$X$ is symmetric about zero](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28992/what-is-the-definition-of-a-symmetric-distribution).  (The converse is equally clear.)

These facts are given in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29), which also mentions this result.