# Is Uniform distribution [a,b] always symmetric?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution, ancillary-statistics

I want to know whether any uniform distributed random variable is symmetric on any interval [a,b].
My thinking is it is symmetric on any interval [a,b].
i tried to think about a counter-example. But I didn't find any.
Is there any?

I want to know this as I want to relate the uniform distribution to the location family, so that I can calculate ancillary statistics.
Because if uniform distribution is symmetric on any interval, then the statistics based on order statistics are always ancillary.

Comment: What's your definition of symmetry?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28992

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by definition of [symmetric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_probability_distribution) "A probability distribution is said to be symmetric if and only if there exists a value $ x_{0}$ such that $f(x_{0}-\delta )=f(x_{0}+\delta )$ for all real numbers 
where f is the probability density function if the distribution is continuous or the probability mass function if the distribution is discrete."

For the Uniform distribution $U[a,b]$ the probability density function is  equal to $\frac{1}{b-a},a<x<b$ or $0,x<a, x>b$,therefore $f(x_{0}-\delta ) 
  =f(x_{0}+\delta )=\frac{1}{b-a}$ for a uniform distribution ($a<x_0-\delta<x_0+\delta<b)$

Comment: My guess is you just did part of this guy's homework...