# $X$, $Y$ independent identically distributed. Are there counterexamples to symmetry of $X-Y$?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, iid, symmetry

That $X-Y$ should be symmetrically distributed for iid $X,Y$ is obvious simply by interchanging the roles of $X$ and $Y$ -- informally we might argue

> Let $Z=X-Y$ have distribution $F$. The roles of which observation was called $X$ and which $Y$ is arbitrary; therefore $-Z=Y-X$ must have the same distribution. If $-Z$ and $Z$ have the same distribution then the distribution is symmetric (about $0$).

However I have a vague recollection of having encountered an odd counterexample at some point (I wonder if it might perhaps have been in the *Counterexamples* book by Romano and Siegel).

Is there some subtlety in the above outlined argument (symmetry in the roles of $X$ and $Y$ implies symmetry of the distribution function) that goes astray in some edge case, or is the implied more formal version of the argument solid? (indicating that I am simply misremembering the notional existence of an exception)

I can't see any obvious way to break it but "I don't see how to do it" doesn't mean much as an argument. I suppose that it may be I have misrecalled some detail; perhaps the exception actually resulted because there wasn't independence in the original formulation (in which case I believe I could find an exception myself).  [Edit: Indeed, I have done so now]

I expect the answer is "no, you're misremembering, obviously it's symmetric" but this nags at me now and then and I worry my notions are flawed in some way.

Comment: This seems neither subtle nor deep.  If you can exchange $X$ and $Y$ and thereby obtain the same joint distribution, then under the exchange $X-Y$ becomes $-(X-Y)$ and it is immediate that $X-Y$ is symmetric about zero.

Comment: @whuber I agree that the notion that there should be symmetry is not at all deep; indeed you seem to just give the same outline of argument I did near the start of the question. The issue of  whether there was some subtlety  would underlie only a positive answer to "did I miss something there?" in my argument (though the answer is, as you say, "no") -- for that argument to have been wrong in some way would seem to require something subtle.

Comment: My point is that the result follows directly from the [definition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29010/919): it's a straightforward application.  There's no need to do any calculation, invoke cfs or cgfs, etc.

Comment: I don't disagree with any of that; I am clear that the doubts I held in that argument were unfounded, but I can't pretend I didn't harbour them anyway.

Comment: An interesting example for a somehat different question to the one here (omitting "independent" and dealing with the sum) is discussed in Chen and Shepp 1983, "On the sum of symmetric random variables", *Am. Stat.* Vol. 37, No 3 .p237 - with an example of two identically distributed Cauchy r.v.s  whose sum is *also* symmetric -- but not about 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Corrected after @Glen_b pointed out a glaring error. Sloppy proof, but should work.*

I think we can prove this using characteristic functions.

Let X, Y be iid. Let Z = Y-X Then,

$\phi_{X-Y}(t) = E[e^{it(X-Y)}] = \phi_X(t)\phi_{-Y}(t)$.

Similar to the CDF, the characteristic function of X uniquely characterizes the distribution of X, and it exists for any real-valued random variable. This implies that $\phi_X(t) \equiv \phi_Y(t)$.

This, along with properties of the characteristic function under linear transformation implies that

$\phi_{-X}(t) =\phi_{X}(-t)  = \phi_{Y}(-t)=\phi_{-Y}(t)  $.

In turn, this implies that

$\phi_X(t)\phi_{-Y}(t) = \phi_X(t)\phi_{-X}(t) = \phi_Y(t)\phi_{-X}(t)  =\phi_{Y-X}(t) $,

so that $\phi_{X-Y}(t)=\phi_{Y-X}(t)$ and $Z \sim -Z$.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clear up the source of my own confusion, I managed to coax just enough (about 4 lines!) out of Google books to resolve the origin of my doubt. It was from Romano and Siegel* and what they actually have there is:

> **4.34**  **Identically distributed random variables such that their difference does not have a symmetric distribution**
>
> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed, then $X-Y$ has a symmetric distribution about zero. The independence assumption cannot be dropped in general. (However, if $X$ and $Y$ are exchangeable, then $X-Y$ does have a symmetric distribution.)

A simple counterexample I came up with is $X\sim U[0,3)$ and $Y=(X-1) \text{ mod } 3$, so $Y$ is also uniform on $[0,3)$ and for which $X-Y$ takes the value $1$ with probability $\frac23$ and $-2$ with probability $\frac13$. This isn't the one I thought of just after I posted the question, but once you have one, further counterexamples are easy to think up and this one is simpler to explain. (Edit: in the end I managed to see their counterexample for the dependent case; it's fine - a simple bivariate example on $\{-1,0,1\}^2$ - but mine's simpler to express so I'll leave it there.)

Note here that $(X,Y)$ doesn't have the same distribution as $(Y,X)$ -- so we don't have the exchangeability that R&S mention, which is why the asymmetry is possible. Note also that the informal argument in my question - "*interchange the roles of $X$ and $Y$*" - quite directly relied on exchangeability and we can see from that outline why that weaker condition should be sufficient to get that $X-Y$ and $Y-X$ have the same distribution.

* Romano, J.P. and Siegel, A.F. (1986),
*Counterexamples in Probability And Statistics*, (Wadsworth and Brooks/Cole Statistics/Probability Series)
(my question was based on a recollection from reading a little of it in late 1986... so it's no surprise I was a little fuzzy on the details)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what prompted the recollection? And, technically you also dropped the "identically distributed" assumption in your example, didn't you?  I can't think of a counterexample that only violates independence off the top of my head, but believe that there would be.

Comment: 1. What prompted my recollection this time was writing a comment under another answer about symmetry of $X-Y$ for independent identically distributed $X,Y$ (in relation to the signed rank test) -- I was suddenly given pause that maybe I had seen a weird counterexample, a doubt that has arisen before. I figured it was time to just resolve it and while I could just have gone and done it (indeed I arrived at what is essentially your final argument shortly after posting my question), I figured it was worth having a question up anyway. ...... ctd

Comment: ctd ...  2.  No, in my example both $X$ and $Y$ are $U[0,3)$. If you have R, try this: `x=runif(10000,0,3);` 
`y=(x-1) %% 3;` 
`par(mfrow=c(2,2));` 
`hist(x,n=30);` 
`hist(y,n=30);` 
`hist(x-y,n=30);` 
`plot(x,y)`  ... .which [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv5uH.png) I think makes the situation clear enough.

Comment: Aha clever. Running a bit slow today apparently