# Equivalence of the probability distribution of a symmetric function = 1/2

Tags: random-variable

> Let $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose the probability density function $f$ of the random variable $X$ satisfies $$f(x-\mu) = f(x+\mu) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R.$$
>   Show that $F(\mu) = \frac{1}{2}$, where $F$ denotes the probability distribution function of $X$,
>   $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\ dt$$

**My Approach**

$$F(+\infty) = 1 \implies
 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)\ dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} f(t)\ dt + \int_{\mu}^{+\infty} f(t)\ dt = 1 $$

i change my variable in $f$ this means that $x-\mu = t \to dx = dt$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{2\mu} f(x-\mu)\ dx + \int_{2\mu}^{+\infty} f(x-\mu)\ dx = 1 $$

and we know that $f(x-\mu) = f(x+\mu)$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{2\mu} f(x+\mu)\ dt + \int_{2\mu}^{+\infty} f(x-\mu)\ dx = 1 $$

but i don't know what i should do .
I think if I can prove in a way that two integrals are equal, the question is solved, but I have no idea to prove their equality. Please help me.

we can understand from $f(x+\mu) = f(x-\mu)$ our function $f$ is a symmetric function.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you mean to write $f(\mu - x) = f(\mu + x)?$ That would be the condition for the distribution being symmetric about $\mu$

Comment: Because this is an immediate consequence of the symmetry, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28992/what-is-the-definition-of-a-symmetric-distribution/29010#29010 for ideas.  For instance, my answer there arrives at this conclusion in a single line.  @Bridgeburners is correct.  Your formulation implies $f$ is *periodic* with period $2\mu.$  There does not exist any such distribution.

Comment: Cross posted on https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2940974/321264.

Comment: $f(x-\mu) = f(x+\mu)\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to $f(x) = f(x+2\mu)\,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and means that $f$ is periodic with period $2\mu$. But $f$ is also a probability density, so for $\mu \neq 0$ the only solution would be $f=0$ a.e.. I think you meant $f(\mu-x) = f(\mu+x)$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Start with the expression,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\mu f(t) dt + \int_\mu^\infty f(t) dt = 1.
$$

On the *first* integral, make the substitution:
$$
t = \mu - x.
$$

On the *second* integral, make the substitution:
$$
t = \mu + x.
$$

Once you do that, you should be able to see how you can use the symmetry condition to make the proof.

Comment: i do this $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x+\mu).dx +\int_{2\mu}^{\infty} f(x-\mu).dx  = 1$ what  i should do next @Bridgeburners

Comment: @alish You made a few mistakes doing the substitutions that I prescribed

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{2\mu} f(x-\mu).dx +\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x+\mu).dx  = 1$ Do i write correctly? @Bridgeburners

Comment: @alish The second one is correct, the first one still has some mistakes in both the argument and the limits. Keep in mind, the sign of the argument matters.

Comment: i see . but i can't understand one matter we know that $f(x-\mu) = f(x+\mu)$ but we have $\int_{0}^{\infty} -f(\mu-x).dx + \int_{0}^{\infty}f(\mu + x).dx = 1$