# A 2 component mixture is symmetric if and only if $\lambda\in \{0,1,\frac{1}{2}\}$

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Consider the following mixture of two densities
$$
f(x)=\lambda g(x-\mu_1)+(1-\lambda)g(x-\mu_2)
$$
with $\lambda\in [0,1]$, $g(\cdot)$ symmetric around zero, $\mu_1<\mu_2$.

**Claim:** the mixture is symmetric if and only if $\lambda\in \{0,1,\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Could you help me to show this? I understand that $\lambda\in \{0,1\}$ implies that the mixture is symmetric because $g(\cdot)$ is symmetric. What I'm struggling to understand is why the weights should be equal to get a symmetric distribution.

Comment: find whether or not there is a $\bar\mu$ such that$$f(x-\bar\mu)=f(\bar\mu-x)\quad\forall x$$

Comment: Directly apply the definition at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28992.