Quantifying a Sequence of Binary Outcomes
I'm compiling a dataset on animal color patterns. Blotches flank the body of the animal (Agkistrodon contortrix) and meet along its midline (i.e., spine). At midline, the blotches can join symmetrically (match perfectly) or asymmetrically (staggered or misaligned entirely). I'm wondering if there is a way to quantify the sequential order of these 10-15 binary (symmetrical or asymmetrical) outcomes. Thus, the final numerical value for an individual animal's color pattern would reflect the total number and grouping (dispersed down the body or typically clumped together) of each of the binary outcomes. If such a method exists, the value would then take on a range with completely symmetrical (like rungs on a ladder) at one extreme to completely asymmetrical (like teeth in a zipper) at the other extreme. The ultimate goal is to regress these data against body size to see if certain color pattern arrangements confer a survival benefit or cost. I appreciate any leads you can share with me.

The animal has a symmetry group generated by the reflection down the middle.  Take any method to quantify the discrepancy between any two possible patterns on the animal (they can be modeled as distributions of colors or even just presence/absence indicators). The method need only (a) not care about which pattern is considered first; (b) return zero only for identical patterns; and (c) otherwise return larger values as patterns depart more.  Apply this method to the animal's pattern and its reflection. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29010/919 for an illustration.

(Continued) That places the onus on you to propose (or invent) a comparison method, or "pseudometric," that is biologically appropriate.  We aren't in a position to suggest what might be appropriate, but I imagine that if (say) the survival benefit arises from eluding the gaze of predators, then an analysis of how those predators perceive things would be an excellent starting point.
